# what does getserializableextra mean in android studio with respect to receiving and Intent Extra

Tags: android, android-intent

Can someone please explain what does `getserializableextra` mean in android studio with respect to receiving and `Intent` Extra. In the context below.

public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{ super.onCreate( savedInstanceState);

```
 UUID crimeId = (UUID) getActivity(). getIntent() .getSerializableExtra( CrimeActivity.EXTRA_CRIME_ID);

 mCrime = CrimeLab.get( getActivity()).getActivity()). getCrime( crimeId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly first it is not the part of `android studio`. you have to clear about `serialize` and `deserialize` object first . check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html).

> To `serialize` an object means to convert its state to a byte stream so
>   that the byte stream can be reverted back into a copy of the object. A
>   Java object is `serializable` if its class or any of its superclasses
>   implements either the `java.io.Serializable` interface or its
>   subinterface, `java.io.Externalizable`. `Deserialization` is the process
>   of converting the `serialized` form of an object back into a copy of the
>   object.